# Decoherence by water?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, decoherence

Decoherence doesn't happen when the double slit experiment is done in air. This is because the sparsely scattered air particles don't contact with the photons that move through it(so I've heard from other answers). Then how about through water? If I conduct the double slit experiment underwater, will the bigger and densely populated water particles contact with the photons so that the photons lose their coherence? Will the stripes not appear on the screen? How about through an even more denser material like a diamond?

Comment: http://www.okphysics.com/6-53-youngs-double-slit-experiment-inside-water/  .. You have to keep in mind that in transparent media coherence is a necessary condition, otherwise the media would not be transparent.

Comment: @Anna V, thanks for the reference. But with all the collisions and scatterings in water, how do the photons stay coherent? Somehow they must, but how does that work? For instance, in fiber optics if there are too many reflections with the glass I believe they loose coherence (I could be wrong)

Comment: @BobBee    The best way to get an intuition on  this is to see a QFT build up of the classical em wave  from a bunch of photons as  in http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html . It also helps to see that the photon has a ground state wave function which in its complex form has the E and B fields that build up the classical em wave  https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0604/0604169.pdf .

Comment: Thanks @Anna V. I will look at those two links. I understand well classical coherence, even when there is scattering, it is something like the correlation time, just not clear how the wave functions stay coherent when they go through a medium where they interact. Will give you feedback.

Comment: So, in essence those two links, and you, are saying that the coherence of the EM classical wave is the same as the coherence of the photons. Is that right? If so, I'm going to have to read more on the classical coherence under scattering etc. maybe my mindset on that is not as clear as I thought.

Comment: @BobBee  I think once more it is the difference between superposition of wavefunctions and probability of interaction. Two laser beams in crossing show interference patterns, is the example of superposition of wavefunction with no interaction ( photon photon interaction is tiny) http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/LaserInterference/LaserInterference.html . In superposition the individual wavefunctions are added and the Psi*Psi of the overall wavfunction gets the phases from the photon wave function with no energy /momentum exchanges for individual photons, just probabilities are affected .

Comment: So , photon impinging on crystal in transparent case has a psi that is non interacting and high probability of going out with same frequency it came in. A superposition of all these photons generates the  em beam which has the classical optics of refraction etc, but it is not interaction really ( except for the absorption)